# как создать табы в material design?

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-material

Как можно сделать такие Табы в андроид?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На данном [сайте](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) находится именно то, что Вам нужно и более того рассматриваются несколько вариаций, а именно просто с текстом, текст+картинка или картинка без текста и Все они соответствуют Material Design. Ну и с подробным описанием, если что-то не получается, то можно скачать код. Только вот я чет не догнал) у Вас в вопросе прям точно такая же картинка как на сайте, который я указал. Вы пробовали уже что-то делать? что-то конкретное не получается?

Comment: нет, еще не пробовал) Просто нашёл картинку.